# How to check if a thread with a certain name is running or not before opening a newer one in C#?

Tags: c#

I am running threads in a loop , but I dont want to run another thread if  there is already a thread running ?

```
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] data = result[i].Split(";");
                string acct = data[0];
                string pass = data[1];
                string serv = data[2];
                if(acct != "" && pass != "" && acct != "")
                { 
                var t = new Thread(() => StartAccountMonitoring(acct , pass , serv));
                t.Name = acct;      //I am using acct value as a name for the thread 
                if(!t.IsAlive)     // here I am trying to check if there is already a thread with a name exist or not if not then open this thread
                    { t.Start(); } 
                }    
            }
```

Comment: Is it appropriate to use thread for this? What does StartAccountMonitoring do?

Comment: its a custom function , this function logs into accounts and then monitor the account and perform calculations . there could be multiple accounts and Idea is to monitor each account in a different thread so it can monitor multiple accounts simultaneously.

Comment: That wouldn't immediately make me think "this must be multithreaded" - if that logging in and monitoring stuff includes a big chunk of sitting around doing nothing other than waiting for IO to complete, doing it with multiple threads might well be a waste of resources and potentially creation of a syncronization headache

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/mutex-objects

Comment: @M_Arad Your computer can only run a small number of threads simultaneously. It's almost always better to think in terms of a queue of tasks that a small number of threads can draw from.

Comment: I'm confused why you are running a loop but only want one instance running

Comment: @TechInquisitor This is something I am concerned about as well , goal is to run this on a server , but is there a way to know how many threads can a computer run simultaneously ?
With 2 cores of CPU ?

Comment: @davidsbro the reason i am running the loop is because there are multiple accounts that needs monitoring , and there is a list of accounts in a csv file so I intend to open a thread for each individual account 

**Each thread will run for ever untill the app is terminated **

Comment: So you don't want two threads watching the same account is what you mean? But you're fine with a thread for each account

Comment: @davidsbro yes , I am still getting my feet wet with multithreading so this approach might no be the best approach , I am open to suggestions if there is a better approach ?
because the account monitoring need to happen all the time , because there are some changes that I aim to catch , so that I can log those changes

Comment: Generally, anything I/O bound should use async/await and the managed thread pool. Only create threads yourself for CPU bound tasks.

Comment: @M_Arad I would look at `Tasks`.

Comment: Choosing to work with threads is to put *mechanism* first and foremost. It's almost always better to work with *logical tasks* and decompose to specific mechanisms as little as possible

Comment: OUTSIDE the loop, declare a `List<Thread>` that you add all of the threads to as you create them from within the loop.  Now you can iterate over them and see if there is one with that name. Even better, you could use a `Dictionary<String, Thread>` and use the name as the key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(() => StartAccountMonitoring(acct,pass,serv));
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
{
    string[] data = result[i].Split(";");
    string acct = data[0];
    string pass = data[1];
    string serv = data[2];
    if(acct != "" && pass != "" && acct != "")
    { 
    var t = new Thread(() => StartAccountMonitoring(acct , pass , serv));
    t.Name = acct;      //I am using acct value as a name for the thread 
    if(myThread == null || !myThread.isAlive){
        myThread = t;
        myThread.Start();
        }
    }    
}
```

Untested.

Something like this is probably what you're looking for. Assign it to a variable and then check the variable's status. You're creating a new temporary variable every time, it never refers to the same thread.

Note that the variable declaration must happen outside of your function that runs multiple times as otherwise the same thing will happen as in your post, you will create a new 'myThread' var every time.

Comment: thank you will give this a shot

Comment: This would allow you to only reference ONE thread, not multiple ones...

Comment: "but I dont want to run another thread if there is already a thread running ?" If intended behavior is wanting to start multiple but only if that instance isn't started, use a List